# How do I import a Java project into Flash Builder 4.7?

Tags: java, flash, flash-builder

Is it possible to work on a Java project inside Flash Builder 4.7? If so I do not know how to import the project.

Also, I might be missing the JDT? I found some instructions here, https://forums.adobe.com/thread/773965?tstart=0 that say to add it via an update site but the instructions were written for Flash Builder 4 not 4.7. It gives a link for using the Galileo update site and I don't want to try it because I don't know if it will mess up my install.

FYI: Flash Builder is based on Eclipse and I don't know how to determine what version of Eclipse Flash Builder 4.7 is based on.

**UPDATE:**
I attempted to go to the next step taking a risk in thinking that it might warn me before installing and it did give me a warning:

```
"Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Eclipse Java Development Tools" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.
```

So it looks like JDT are already installed but still do not see any way to import the Java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB 4.7 is based on eclipse indigo version, it's possible to import a java project on FB.
I'm using Maven to build my project but you can import a general java project.
i'v tried all these solution and all works fine :

Solution 1: change your Java project to Maven project nature with your eclipse, and import it on FB: 
             import>Maven>Existing Maven Project.

Solution 2: like any Java project import>General>Existing Projects into Workkspace.

Solution 3: check your .project file and verify that it's correct.

Solution 4: move your project folder into your workspace and create new Java project with FB with a
            similar name as your project folder, this will create a new Java project with FB with 
            your old Java project files.

Solution 5: do it in inverse: install FB 4.7 plugin in your eclipse and import your flex project to 
            to eclipse.

for jdt plugin error, FB 4.7 use eclipse JDT plugin 3.7.1.r371 and it work fine with this version